# Conditional column value, Select

Tags: sql, oracle

I got 2 tables "Records" and "Char". With 1 -> N relation
I need to make a select, with a subquery/join where the value to present on the join column is a fixed string like "Multiple Chars" or the content Char.char_val

Let me illustrate:

Records:

```
     R_ID | Name        Char: C_ID | R_ID | Char_Val
        1    A                 1        3     c1
        2    B                 2        1     c2
        3    C                 3        1     c3
                               4        2     c3
```

Expected Result:

```
       R_ID | Name  |   Char_Val
        1    A      Multiple Records
        2    B              c3
        3    C              c1
```

I guess my query would be something like:

```
Select r.R_ID, r.Name, (conditional select) Char_Val
From Records r, Char c
where r.R_ID = c.R_ID
```

Suggestions for the (conditional select)?

Comment: you can use `listagg` for this purpose

Comment: You should not use 1980s joins anymore. Use proper ANSI joins instead (`From Records r Join Char c On r.R_ID = c.R_ID`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by r_id. Either MIN = MAX or you want 'Multiple Records':

```
select r_id, r.name, c.char_vals
from
(
  select 
    r_id,
    case when min(char_val) = max(char_val) then min(char_val) else 'Multiple Records' end 
      as char_vals
  from char
  group by r_id
) c
join records r using(r_id)
order by r_id;
```

Comment: On the spot! The most clean/elegant answer. Note for future readers: I made a **right join** instead to show R_ID and Name of records with no Char_Val associated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement and aggregation to get a fixed string:

```
case when count(c.c_id) > 1 then 'Multiple Records' else max(c.char_val) end
```

and you need to group by `r_id` and `name`:

```
select r.r_id, r.name,
  case when count(c.c_id) > 1 then 'Multiple Records'
    else max(c.char_val) end as char_val
from records r
join char c on r.r_id = c.r_id
group by r.r_id, r.name
order by r.r_id;
```

I've also switched to use ANSI joins instead of the old syntax (as @Thorsten suggested).

This is a demo using CTE to generate your data, giving them slightly different names because `char` is a reserved word:

```
with t_records (r_id, name) as (
  select 1, 'A' from dual
  union all select 2, 'B' from dual
  union all select 3, 'C' from dual
),
t_char (c_id, r_id, char_val) as (
  select 1, 3, 'c1' from dual
  union all select 2, 1, 'c2' from dual
  union all select 3, 1, 'c3' from dual
  union all select 4, 2, 'c3' from dual
)
select r.r_id, r.name,
  case when count(c.c_id) > 1 then 'Multiple Records'
    else max(c.char_val) end as char_val
from t_records r
join t_char c on r.r_id = c.r_id
group by r.r_id, r.name
order by r.r_id;    

      R_ID N CHAR_VAL        
---------- - ----------------
         1 A Multiple Records
         2 B c3              
         3 C c1
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query gives the result (with **Char_val** separated by comma) you expected:

```
Select r.R_ID, r.Name, listagg(c.char_val,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY c.char_val) AS Char_Val
From Records r, Char c
where r.R_ID = c.R_ID
GROUP BY r.R_ID, r.Name
```

Comment: That isn't the output the OP expected though; they said they wanted a fixed string like "Multiple Chars", though they then showed a different fixed string "Multiple Records" in the expected result. It doesn't say they want the actual values from the multiple rows?